# Android emulator (Nexus S) no longer runs app after installing new AVD

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I run Android Studio I was using an emulator, Nexus S, on the Marshmallow OS (6.0). To try on different devices, I installed Google Pixel emulator w/ Nougat OS. It failed to run so I uninstalled it. Now when I run Nexus S emulator with Marshmallow I get two errors. I assume it is a result of the installations of files for Nougat earlier but I don't know where to find these extra files and don't really have the experience to figure this out without screwing up even further.

The errors appear only in MainActivity.java, as seen below.It is a basic app to increase or decrease the quantity of "coffees" ordered and a basic mathematical expression calculating the net cost. From the Udacity course on android app development: https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud836

```
package com.example.android.justjava;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

/**
 * This app displays an order form to order coffee.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/**
 * This method is called when the + button is clicked.
 */
public void increment(View view) {
    int quantity = 2;
    quantity = 3;
    display(quantity);
}

/**
 * This method is called when the - button is clicked.
 */
public void decrement(View view) {
    int quantity = 1;
    display(quantity);
}

/**
 * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
 */
public void submitView view) {
    int coffeesNum = 2;
    display(coffeesNum);
    displayPrice(coffeesNum * 5);
}
/**
 * This method displays the given price on the screen.
 */
private void displayPrice(int number) {
    TextView priceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price_text_view);
    priceTextView.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(number));
}

/**
 * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
 */
private void display(int number) {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
}
```

}

The first error occurs on line 40: "error: '(' expected"
The second error occurs also on line 40: "error:  expected"
I know they're both correct as I pasted them from the course.

Help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That line `public void submitView view)` should be

> public void submit (View view)

You must have mistakenly edited the file. That is whats wrong with `line 40`.